# Validate an input from user

Tags: c#, validation

I have to write a console program to obtain test scores and set the maximum value to be greater than 0 and no less than the highest score obtained but I am stuck on the validation of the "maxscore".

This is what I have so far:

```
int[] score = new int[5];
int highScore = 0;
int sum = 0;
int ave = 0;

//Requests the user to input 5 numbers
Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 test scores:");

//Obtains the input and sets the highScore as well as the sum for all the number entered

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    score[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (i > highScore)
    {
        highScore = i;
        sum += score[i];
    }
}

//Requests the user to enter the max score
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the max score:");
int maxScore = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: So you want to validate that the user knows the max number between the 5 numbers he already provided ?

Comment: In your if you check the i instead of score[i]

Comment: This program doesn't make sense. Also, Stack overflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake when comparing `highScore` with `i` instead of `score[i]`. And then you should also `highScore = score[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between the index `i` and the score `score[i]`. `i` is the counter, which you are using as the *index to the array element*, while `score[i]` is the actual value of the score inside the array named `score`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    score[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (score[i] > highScore)
    {
        highScore = score[i];
        sum += score[i];
    }
}
```